# Clicking on a link that contains a certain string in VBS

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to run an automated vbs script that clicks on a link on a page. I have things of the form:

```
Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4  
Set IE = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")  
IE.Visible = true  
IE.navigate ("http://mywebpage.com")
```

How do I then make it click on a link on that page that doesn't have an ID but is like

```
<a href="link">ClickMe!</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm presuming you know the value of the link (ie: ClickMe!)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Along the lines of

```
Dim LinkHref
Dim a

LinkHref = "link"

For Each a In IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A")
  If LCase(a.GetAttribute("href")) = LCase(LinkHref) Then
    a.Click
    Exit For  ''# to stop after the first hit
  End If
Next
```

Instead of `LCase(…) = LCase(…)` you could also use `StrComp(…, …, vbTextCompare)` (see [`StrComp()` on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya4w6fwy%28VS.85%29.aspx)).