# Using VBA to click a link

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying next to click a link to view information on a page using VBA to then move on to edit that information with VBA, But trying to figure out how to write the code for it as the ID information changes with each search,

Any ideas on this?

I've looked around and can't seem to understand how to get VBA to pick this line up as the (ID=) and it isn't joined to the same ID as I'm searching for.

There is also serval references for

This is the line of code.

```
<a href="/?do_Action=ViewEntity&amp;Entity_ID=14287">View</a>
```

This is my current code to do the search for it. Without clicking on the view section yet.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim form As Variant
    Dim button As Variant
    Dim LR As Integer
    Dim var As String

    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To LR
        var = Cells(x, 1).Value
        Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
        ie.Visible = True

        With ie
            .Visible = True
            .navigate "*******"

            While Not .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            Wend
        End With

        'Wait some to time for loading the page
        While ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Wend

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        ie.document.getElementById("quicksearch").Value = var

        'code to click the button
        Set form = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("form")
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Set button = form(0).onsubmit
        form(0).submit

        'wait for page to load
        While ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Wend
    Next x
End Sub
```

Edited

I've added in the code I think it should be following that link and a bit of tinkering to get it to not error with compiler errors :D, All seems to work but when it get's to the line to click the link it doesn't fail but doesn't even click it. It will then move on to the next one in the list in the spreed sheet, Which is expected.

Following it through with the debugger that shows nothing erroring or failing which is what I expect it to do if the code was wrong or link,

Any help, please ?

This is the code now

```
Sub Test1()
Dim ie As Object
Dim form As Variant
Dim button As Variant
Dim LR As Integer
Dim var As String
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To LR
var = Cells(x, 1).Value
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
ie.Visible = True
Dim a
Dim linkhref
linkhref = "/?do_Action=ViewEntity&amp;Entity_ID"

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "*******"
    While Not .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Wend
End With
 'Wait some to time for loading the page
While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
ie.document.getElementById("quicksearchbox").Value = var
 'code to click the button
  Set form = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("form")
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
  Set button = form(0).onsubmit
  form(0).submit
  'wait for page to load
  While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
  Wend
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
   For Each a In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
   If (a.getAttribute("href")) = ("/?do_Action=ViewEntity&amp;Entity_ID=") Then
   a.Click
   Exit For
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
   While ie.Busy
   DoEvents
   Wend
   End If
   Next
   Next x 


End Sub
```

This is a copy of the code around the buttons,

```
This is the code surrounding the buttons,
<a href="/?do_Action=ViewEntity&amp;Entity_ID=14287">View</a> 
<a href="/?do_Action=DecomRequest&amp;Entity_ID=14287">Decom</a> 
<a href="/?do_Action=ViewServerLog&amp;Entity_ID=14287">Log</a></td>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Check every `<a>` tag and make an If without the id number. Something like `If Left(ThisElement.href, 37) = "/?do_Action=ViewEntity&amp;Entity_ID=" Then...`

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Clicking on a link that contains a certain string in VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772239/clicking-on-a-link-that-contains-a-certain-string-in-vbs). Note that code is in VBScript, but it should be very similar or almost identical in VBA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clicking on a link that contains a certain string in VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772239/clicking-on-a-link-that-contains-a-certain-string-in-vbs)

Comment: I've updated it with code but either option i swap out for will not click the link. Am I missing something obvious, I'm still learning VBA. So if any pointers let me know

Answer (score 0):

If the element `href` is something like `"/?do_Action=ViewEntity&amp;Entity_ID=14287"`, this `if` statement is never going to evaluate to `True`:

```
(a.getAttribute("href")) = ("/?do_Action=ViewEntity&amp;Entity_ID=")
```

So the element will never be clicked.

If you know the `Entity_ID` you want to click you can do:

```
Dim Entity_ID as Integer

Entity_ID = 14287
If (a.getAttribute("href")) = "/?do_Action=ViewEntity&amp;Entity_ID=" & Cstr(myID) Then a.click
```

Otherwise just check if the element `href` contains that url:

```
If InStr(1, a.getAttribute("href"), linkhref) > 0 Then a.click
```

**EDIT**

Ok, using the HTML you posted I am able to access the specified `a` tag that you requested, by doing this

```
For Each ele In ie.document.getElementById("searchresults").getElementsByTagName("a")
   If InStr(1, ele.href, "do_Action=ViewEntity") > 0 Then
       MsgBox "The button is found!"
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it hasn't worked, I've tried both. The ID sadly a unique generated one which doesn't match up with the ID of the item search at the beginning. So in a sense have to tell it to find that tag /?do_Action=ViewEntity&amp;Entity_ID= and click it. What is strange it doesn't fail it just doesn't click.

Comment: Since you are using an instance of Internet Explorer, doesn't  `ie.navigate a.getAttribute("href")` work for you?

Comment: Just tried it and loops the page back to the beginning which it has never done. So I would say that is an improvement :D, The only problem with that code is there is serval href ref in it I need it to pick out the correct one. I've added them to the original post for you.

Comment: As I know the unique ID for this one I'm searching, Even putting that in loops it back to the beginning. Before I put this code in it used to go past this bit and open another IE to do the next search. I think it doesn't like me :D

Comment: What do you mean "several href in it and I need pick out the correct one" ? According to the code you posted, there is only one button with `do_Action=ViewEntity` in its href..

Comment: Correct that is it,but there is other with ref to href. I may be getting confused here, As for example if I used this ie.navigate a.getAttribute("href"), I would need to define it to pick the correct one correct, Or have I miss understood it all ?

Comment: You have defined `linkhref = "/?do_Action=ViewEntity&amp;Entity_ID"` so putting this if statement `If InStr(1, a.getAttribute("href"), linkhref) > 0 Then ie.navigate a.getAttribute("href")` will make sure you navigate to the desired page.

Comment: I've tried this and still loops back to the main page, As if it is hitting the logo on click, Which it shouldn't be able to. 
This is the code now.

  'code'
  wend
  
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

For Each a In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

If InStr(1, a.getAttribute("href"), linkhref) > 0 Then ie.navigate 

a.getAttribute("href")

a.Click

Exit For

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

While ie.Busy

DoEvents

Wend

Next

Next x

End Sub'

Comment: Sorry the code seems to all jumble together, How do I get it to spread out like my original code, As the shortcut don't seem to work in comment section

Comment: I think you should edit your post and post the full html code for that particular page...it is very difficult to tell whats wrong without seeing the actual page

Comment: I've added it in, Got fed up with the codebreaker not showing full, So it is in a snippet thing.

Comment: That works in a sense the box pop's up now in excel to say it has found it. But when changing it to a click. Still, nothing clicks. I feel like i'm missing something very obvious here :(

Comment: If the button is found and the `click` method is not working then I suspect that there is a problem with that webpage, but can't think of anything else to solve this. That exact same method works with other pages.

Comment: Is this correct setup for the code, Checking line by line through debug it pulls the correct line just no click.  

` For Each ele In ie.document.getElementById("searchresults").getElementsByTagName("a") `
      `If InStr(1, ele.href, "do_Action=ViewEntity") > 0 Then
      a.Click
      End If
      Next
     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))`
     While ie.Busy
     DoEvents
     Wend
     Next x`

Answer (score 0):

Use a For to check every `<a>` tag element and make sure you click the right one. It's true your ID changes, but rest of string is constant, so that's 1 factor. Also, it looks like you always will click where it says `View` so that's another constant.

With both options, we can develop a simple For..Next that will check every `<a>` element and will check if those 2 options requirements are fulfilled:

```
For Each a In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
   If Left(a.href, 37) = "/?do_Action=ViewEntity&amp;Entity_ID=" And a.innerText = "View" Then
    a.Click
    Exit For
Next a
```

Try it and let's see if this works for you.

Comment: Tried it sadly still no click. It will go on to the next item that it should for search, So not erroring in a  way from what  I can see. I'm trying to understand it but not making any sense as to why it not erroring.
The end bit of code now 
`Wend
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
For Each a In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
If Left(a.href, 37) = "/?do_Action=ViewEntity&amp;Entity_ID=" And a.innerText = "View" Then
   a.Click
   Exit For
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
   While ie.Busy
   DoEvents
   Wend
   End If
   Next a
   Next x`

Comment: Can we see the URL? That would make possible to make some tests before posting a code

Comment: Sadly not the URL is only accessible internally and can't be viewed externally or would give it as would help you guys.

Comment: This is what the URL looks like after the link view been hit, 
`https://*******/?do_Action=ViewEntity&Entity_ID=14287`

Comment: Execute code step by step and check if it goes inside the If in any moment.

Comment: I'm just doing it, It looks like to me through the step process not pulling the correct herf, As this is what is pulled ` : href : "https://******/?do_action=ViewDC&dc_datacenter=******" : String!` If I understand that correctly. I'm still learning and trying to understand it all, I see nothing for View Entity in the list on the drop in section of debuging.

Comment: You need to isolate the exactly href you need, and then adapt the part that says `If Left(a.href, 37) = "/?do_Action=ViewEntity&amp;Entity_ID=" And a.innerText = "View" Then`. I can't do it because i can't access to that url, so you must do it.