# VBS Click on Button by href

Tags: javascript, vbscript, click

**Using VBScript**

I am trying to click a button on a webpage with the following elements:

`<a class="pds-return-poll" href="javascript:PDV_go9994806();">Return To Poll</a>`

Since I'm using IE as my web browser, I thought IE.document.all.item("pds-return-poll").click would work, but it says there's no object.

Any idea on how to click on a button that gives a javascript href??
Or do some websites block the .click function for certain objects?

Comment: You want [getElementsByClassName](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44853941/11683).

Comment: Is that supported for internet explorer?
I tried it but an error saying the object doesn't support that command popped up.

Comment: Found a good answer!!

Please see [Click on href with VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772239/clicking-on-a-link-that-contains-a-certain-string-in-vbs) for best answer.